# how to send custom metrics from Jmeter to InfluxDB

Tags: jmeter, influxdb

We are creating custom metrics in JMeter using beanshell scripting and saving them to a file.Our requirement is to send this metrics to InfluxDB. We tried using Backend Listener with Graphite and InfluxDB implementation client but couldn't send the custom values. Only the default Jmeter metrics are being passed.
Has anyone done this before, can you guide us to resolve this issues.
We are using Jmeter 3.3 and influxdb-1.4.2-1

Thanks,
BB

Comment: Can you tell us the name of the client tool used for quering the data from Influxdb in above answer?

Answer (score 2):

Two words: [line protocol](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.4/write_protocols/line_protocol_reference/).
Another two words: custom listener (Beanshell/JSR223 with Groovy).

Marry them, and you'll have what you want.

I did that work once, and it didn't take long.

There may be other options (like, take this result file and feed it to script that shapes it to the same line protocol, but post-execution, not live) - but the one I suggest is the simplest.

Answer (score 0):

To do it you can use /write endpoint as it described in [influxdb.com](https://influxdbcom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/content/docs/v0.9/guides/writing_data/)

Image below shows how it can be done in Jmeter using "HTTP Request" sampler.

How to send custom data to influxDB:

[image: How to send custom data to influxDB]

In a DB it will looks like on image below:

[image: Custom variable in InfluxDB]